# Geometric quotients of DM stacks by group actions

Tags: stacks, algebraic-stacks, coarse-moduli-spaces, quotient-space

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a DM stack $X$ and $Y$ the quotient stack. I.e., $Y \to BG$ has fiber $X$. Is there a geometric quotient $X/G$ in some sense? I want automorphism groups of points to surject under the map $X \to X/G$. E.g., if $X \to Z$ has that property and is $G$-invariant, I want the relative coarse moduli space of $Y \to Z$. If $G$ acts trivially, $X/G$ should just give back $X$.

I think this is related to $(X/G) // G$, where $//$ is the \fatslash rigidification symbol. But this rigidification is not defined to my knowledge unless $G$ injects into the automorphism group of each object.

My guess at its functor of points: the initial DM stack $T$ with a map $Y \to T$ such that $f : X \to Y \to T$ has $Aut_X(x) \to Aut_T(f(x))$ surjective.

It's the opposite of the relative coarse moduli space of $Y \to BG$. But is there another way to view this as a relative coarse moduli space?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion on the representability that is expected : in fact $X\to X/G$ is always representable in your situation, but it is not the same to ask for $X/G$ to be representable over some $Z$. In fact, the notion of "representability over $Z$" depends on which $G$-invariant map $X\to Z$ you take.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu! I'm trying to understand your paper at the moment. I should not have said "representability." I think I fixed it now. My apologies.